# Static site using Gulp & Jade, cannonical URLs

Tags: pug, gulp, canonical-link, static-site

I've been trying to switch a site over from using Jekyll to using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com) & [Jade](http://jade-lang.com); it was mainly using Jekyll because of the convenience of it's templating, but Jekyll's real use is as a blog, so more of it's features point that way. Developing company websites in it works but things like `watch` are missing unless you use the dev server. It also has the advantage of using Jade's syntax and `npm` though doubtless there are Jade plugins for Jekyll.

One thing Jekyll was good to point out is that the cannoical URL structure a.g. `mydomain.com/about` that we're used to using with routed dynamic sites (e.g. with `mod_rewrite`) can be very easily achieved with directory structures: `./about/index.html`

This does mean that sites can generate a lot of folders, so moving to Jade I want to keep it to a minimum. This is the code to use `gulp jade` to generate `.html` from `.jade` files:

```
gulp.task('jade',function(callback){
    gulp.src('./jade/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
        pretty: true,
        markdown:marked
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));

    callback();
});
```

How can I alter this to get:

```
jade/index.jade -> public/index.html
jade/about.jade -> public/about/index.html
jade/another-page.jade -> public/another/page/index.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a previous project I'd used the `gulp-rename` library to allow for quick switching of config files into a build directory. Turns out it does more than just regex and passing a function into it presents you with a useful object

```
path={
  basename:'about',
  dirname:'',
  extname:'html'
}
```

Changing these values alters the rename, no `return` value required. So with a quick check for the main `index.jade` file we can do a quick split and join to form a directory path, which `gulp.dest` will create for us if it doesn't exist.

```
var jade=require('gulp-jade');
var rename=require('gulp-rename');
gulp.task('jade',function(callback){
    gulp.src('./jade/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
        pretty: true,
        markdown:marked
    }))
    .pipe(rename(function(path){
        if (path.basename=='index'){
            return;
        }
        path.dirname=path.basename.split('-').join('/');
        path.basename="index";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));

    callback();
});
```